# Windows CMD FTP with Truncate option

Tags: cmd, ftp, word-wrap, file-transfer, truncate

I'd like to transfer a text file from Windows to Mainframe, but I only need the first 80 columns.

I set my DSN on Mainframe with 80 columns but my file has different line sizes, all larger than 80.
When I run the simple 'PUT' or 'SEND' FTP command I get this message:

```
ftp> send "EXP.txt" 'k1111.du11111.EXP'
200 Port request OK.
125 Storing data set K1111.DU11111.EXP
250 Transfer completed (lines were wrapped)
```

The point here is this message "Lines were wrapped".

This result "lines were wrapped" produces the file in Mainframe, but it has a larger number of lines than the original file, with content that distrubs the posterior reading.
I'd like to avoid this Wrapped lines, or even better I'd like to truncate the lines to just the lenght I'll use.

Comment: Can you not use something like `cut` from [`unxUtils`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) or write a script that takes your file and line length (`n`) as input, reads in each line of input and outputs the first `n` characters per line (or whole line if shorter than `n`) to output (such as `stdout` or another file)?

Comment: It could be done, but my point is about the operation of the FTP tool and its options.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the purpose of the FTP tool is getting data files from A to B, not the manipulation of their content when doing so.

Comment: Fine, but in this case i think we can consider the action of wrap lines as a kind of manipulation - The number of lines increased and the format of the columns is modified. I wish I could at least avoid this wrap.

Comment: Is zipping the files and/or forcing `ftp` to send them as binary (octet streams) out of the question? That might stop it from tampering with their content(s).

Comment: How could we do this?